# How can you throttle bandwidth usage on the receiving side of a video stream in ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, bandwidth, rtmp, bandwidth-throttling

Right now I'm on a project that's moving video streams across RTMP using mostly ActionScript 3.0 (a little bit of 2.0 is used on the server side), and we already have functionality in place to throttle bandwidth usage for these video streams on the client level.  However we're only doing that by calling the setQuality() method of class Camera, which affects every receiver of that video stream.  Now though we really need a way to effectively set the bandwidth usage for individual receivers, but apparently VideoDisplay, NetStream, and NetConnection are all pretty much void of this sort of functionality.  Is there not some decent way to do this in AS3?  If there is a way, how?  Thanks!

EDIT: For clarity let's say that the sender of the video stream has their Camera object's quality set to use 1 meg of bandwidth.  How could I make a receiver of that stream only use half a meg of bandwidth to stream that video in without messing with the sender's 1 meg setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FMS just passes data received from publisher to the set of subscribers. It's doesn't change it (at least from the data point of view). What you require, though, is transcoding of the video stream being published according to subcriber needs.
Simple RTMP dosn't do that at all. I think there is a way to publish multiple streams for the same data using http streaming feature. But, in that case, the publisher would really be publishing multiple streams of the media to FMS.